# Get data from between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables

[image: EXPENSES Table]

[image: EXPENSENAME]

The first one is expenses table and the second one is expensename

Exp_Type(first table) is the Expense name(second table) as 2 is Food

I am trying to group expense according to expense type and get data between certain dates.

This is what i have tried, but it wont work.

```
select
(select 
(select name from EXPENSENAME where id=EXP_TYPE)as ExpenseType,
sum(PRICE) as cost
from EXPENSES WHERE USERID=1  GROUP BY EXPENSES.EXP_TYPE),
[date]
from EXPENSES where [date] BETWEEN '10-09-2015' and '10-18-2015 23:59:59'

And

select 
(select name from EXPENSENAME where id=EXP_TYPE)as ExpenseType,
sum(PRICE) as cost,
date
from EXPENSES WHERE USERID=1 and DATE BETWEEN '01/10/2015' and '29/10/2015' GROUP BY EXPENSES.EXP_TYPE
```

With out date, i am getting result by this query but i need the same data between certain dates,please help

```
select 
(select name from EXPENSENAME where id=EXP_TYPE)as ExpenseType,
sum(PRICE) as cost
from EXPENSES WHERE USERID=1  GROUP BY EXPENSES.EXP_TYPE
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to join the tables together

```
SELECT en.name as ExpenseType, SUM(e.price) as cost
FROM expenses e
JOIN expensename en ON en.id = e.exp_type
WHERE e.date BETWEEN '10-09-2015' and '10-18-2015'
GROUP BY en.name
```

this should give you the cost per name

the current query you have is TERRIBLE... and this is why

```
SELECT (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ) as ...
```

this is creating a correlated subquery which is executing once for every row of the parent select. meaning if you have a table with 4 rows in it `(SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... )` will execute 4 times scanning 16 rows (assuming its from the same table) in general that is a really really bad way to get data... if you have a million rows... well do the math, its a bad idea